# Rails session_store key change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-cookies

I need to preserve the user sessions even after I deploy a change on the session_store key:

Before deployment:

`MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, key: '_abc_session'`

After deployment:

`MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, key: '_xyz_session'`

Users should still be able to use the old `key` even after this change is made.

Any idea about how to make the **old** key valid even after the deployment?

Answer (score 2):

For old sessions to work you need to make the app read from both keys, but only write to new. This approach was used by rails when switching from marshalled sessions to json (`:hybrid` mode)

Something like this should do (have not tested, also your rack version may be different, so better come up with your variant):

```rb
class MyHybridStore < ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore
  # this lives in Rack::Session::Abstract::Persisted (this is modified from rack 2.1.2, yours may differ)
  def unpacked_cookie_data(request)
    request.fetch_header(RACK_SESSION_UNPACKED_COOKIE_DATA) do |k|
      # the trick:
      session_data = request.cookies[@key].presence || request.cookies['_abc_session']

      if @secrets.size > 0 && session_data
        session_data, _, digest = session_data.rpartition('--')
        session_data = nil unless digest_match?(session_data, digest)
      end

      request.set_header(k, coder.decode(session_data) || {})
    end
  end
end

MyApp::Application.config.session_store MyHybridStore, key: '_xyz_session'
```

Comment: Can `key:` support an array ? `key: ['_xyz_session', '_abc_session']` ?

Comment: @Vasfed where can I find more info about this approach?